# Where can I find this paper by Iwasawa?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, function-fields

I'm trying to find a copy of the 1969 article *Analogies between number fields and function fields* by Iwasawa. There is a similar paper by Wiles and Mazur titled *Analogies between function fields and number fields* which is easily found online, but I cannot seem to locate Iwasawa's paper anywhere. The reference can be found here, https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0255510.

Comment: If you are in the U.S.A. you might see it here https://catalog.hathitrust.org/api/volumes/oclc/1403342.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is contained in the [Collected Papers](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9784431550556) published by Springer, as [47] on pp. 599 – 604.

It can be found in libraries, purchased <s>and/or found lying around online</s>.